# Why would a language created by humans lack both the /s/ and the /z/ consonants?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, language, vampires, vocalizations

In my story, there are a strange species from the *Homo* genus: hematophagous humans often called vampires (their scientific name is *Homo haematophagus*) (so, they are still humans, just not *Homo sapiens*).

I think the /s/ and the /z/ consonants are the most common fricatives around the world (except for maybe the /f/ and the /v/ consonants, and the /h/ sound).

However, in the most spoken language used by vampires, there are no the /s/ and the /z/ consonants. There are eight fricatives in that language: /f/, /v/, the sound corresponding to the French *ch* (as in French *cheval*) (*cheval* means horse), the sound corresponding to the French *j* (as in French *jeu*) (*jeu* means game), the sound corresponding to the voiceless English th (as in English thief), and the sound corresponding to the voiced English th (or the Albanese *dh*) (as in English brother), the /x/ sound (as in Spanish *ojo* which means eye), and the sound corresponding to the *g* in Spanish *amigo* (which means friend).

There are also two nasal consonants: /m/ as in English mother, and /n/ as in English night.

There are also six plosives: /p/ as in English principality, /b/ as in English beauty, /t/ as in English turtle, /d/ as in English dementia, /k/ as in English kilogram, and /g/ as in English green.

There is the /l/ sound as in English lesbian.

Also, the rhotic sound used in the most spoken language used by vampires is the voiced alveolar trill (the rhotic sound used in Slavic languages, some Germanic languages such as Dutch, and Icelandic, and most Italic languages such as Italian, and Romanian).

In the most spoken language used by vampires, there are seven simple vowels: /a/ (as in French *abeille*) (*abeille* means bee), /i/ (as in English hippie) (hippie is also used in French), /u/ (as in French *ouvrier*) (*ouvrier* means worker), /y/ (as in French *univers*) (*univers* naturally means universe), the sound corresponding to the *a* in English fall (or the *o* in French *ordinateur*) (*ordinateur* means computer), the sound corresponding to the French *eu* (or the German *ö*) (as in French *euphémisme*) (*euphémisme* naturally means euphemism), and the sound corresponding to the French *è* (as in French *pègre*) (*pègre* means underworld).

Finally, in the most spoken language used by vampires, there are all the three semivowels used in French (in other words, the /j/ sound as in English yellow, and in French *hyène*, the /w/ sound as in English world, and in French *oiseau*, and the sound corresponding to the *u* in the French word *fruit*) (these three French words respectively mean hyena, bird, and fruit).

So, I wonder why would a language created by mammals from the *Homo* genus lack both the /s/ and the /z/ consonants.

Comment: How do the vampires talk to non vampires without any esses or ezzes?

Comment: This seems like a textbook idea generation question where you're wanting us to brainstorm for you and make up ideas about your world. As a rule we discourage questions with many valid answers. Given the many reasons why phonemes have been added to or removed from dialects and languages in the real world. What makes you think that the answers to this question will be any less broad and varried?

Comment: This is another in the series of question where real-world human language accidents are spoken as if they were something fantastic. For a quick reminder, Greek only has the fricatives /s/ and /z/, and lacks /f/, /v/, /ʃ/ (French *chef*), and /ʒ/ (French *jeu*). For example, the [Tamil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_language) language has 80 million speakers and does not have the phonemes /s/ and /z/. (It does have a *phone* [s], as an allophone of /t͡ɕ/ in some contexts, and /z/ appears in loan-words.) [Hawaiian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_language) is another example.

Comment: It would help if the opening would indicate - explicitly - whether we're looking for a physiological difference special for vampires, or cultural choice or language. In case of physiology, a creature design tag could be added.. in case of culture or language, it may be (very !) broad and story based..

Comment: Possibly better for https://conlang.stackexchange.com/ than here... although @AlexP has the correct answer here already.

Comment: Same reason Japanese contains no L sound: just because.

Comment: As written, this question is entirely opinion based. It can be made much less opinion based if you dropped all the verbiage about French and Dutch and other irrelevant things, plainly list the invented language's phonological inventory, and offer some helpful context about this Vampiric language. Even though AlexP gave you counterexamples, he didn't tell you *why*.

Comment: If you're talking about something specific to vampires, then it's possible they have structural issues in their tongue that makes those sounds hard to pronounce. If it's just the language of their homeland, then there is no point of differentiation.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### TL;DR

There do exist human languages, and not even exotic languages spoken by a handful of illiterate people in remote jungles, which do not have /s/ and /z/. It's not something fantastic, and it doesn't need any explanation.

### Hawaiian

The [Hawaiian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_language) language, spoken in Hawaii, a rather well-known and very beautiful archipelago in the Pacific Ocean, does not have /s/ and /z/.

The Hawaiian alphabet is:

- A, E, I,  O, U, H, K, L, M, N, P, W, ʻ.

That's it. No S, and no Z.

<sup>Like all Polynesian languages, Hawaiian uses a fairly phonemic spelling. The only consonants in [Hawaiian phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_phonology) are /h/, /t/⁓/k/ (in free variation, written K), /l/⁓/ɾ/⁓/ɹ/ (in free variation, written L), /m/, /n/, /p/, /w/⁓/v/ (in free variation, written W), and /ʔ/ (glottal stop, written ʻ).</sup>

### Tamil

[Tamil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_language) is a language spoken by 80 million people in India.

It does not have the phonemes /s/ and /z/. It *does* have a [*phone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_(phonetics)) [s], as an [allophone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allophone) of /t͡ɕ/ in certain contexts; and /z/ does appear in modern loan-words, and it may be on its way to becoming a regular phoneme.

<sup>Languages are not static. For example, my own language, Romanian, is normally described as lacking front rounded vowels. But the French influence has been so great during the last two centuries that a handful of French words have been adopted with their front rounded vowels unchanged: so that now words like *bleu*, *alură* and *tul* (from French *bleu*, *allure* and *tulle*) create headaches to Romanian lexicographers who need to find some way to indicate their pronunciation -- /blø/, /a'lyrə/ and /tyl/...</sup>

### In general

Whatever you think is a linguistic universal, think again. If you really truely find something which holds universally for all human languages, *jump* to the opportunity to have your name immortalized in [*Glossa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossa_(journal)).

Comment: Of course, lacking the *letters* "S" and "Z" doesn't necessarily mean the language lacks /s/ and /z/.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-: Of course, there is a link in the answer going to the Wikipedia article about the Hawaiian language, which explains how Hawaiian spelling works and even links to a detailed article about Hawaiian phonology. (And Polynesian languages do indeed tend to be spelled phonemically. If you know of a Polynesian language which uses a spelling system far removed from the spoken reality I would like very much to hear about it.)

Comment: @AlexP I think Azor's comment was to highlight the fact that _in general_ this is not a cause-and-effect relationship, and that any letter or combination of letters _could_ be voiced /s/ or /z/, not that specifically in the case of Hawaiian either sound actually exists.

Comment: The random WB reader probably doesn't know Polynesian orthography that well. Besides, even if a language is spelled phonemically, that doesn't mean the phonemes line up with values the colonizing language uses. E.g. Russian doesn't use <R> but does have /r/, represented by <P>. There's another language that uses some surprising values for the Latin letters but I can't find what I'm thinking of ...

Comment: And I know Russian isn't an example of a colonizing orthography, but just to point out graphemes don't have universal sound values.

Comment: Well, there's always Irish or Welsh, which only use the Latin alphabet because it confuses the English. Or something. :)

Comment: Would you be okay with an edit that replaces the "not even exotic languages spoken by a handful of people in the remote jungles of Papua" part by something more neutral, perhaps "not even languages spoken only by a handful of speakers"? I know that the current wording is meant ironically, but it still plays on the idea that the Papuan languages may not be as relevant as other languages after all.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Russian /r/ isn't represented by P; it's represented by Р; Cyrillic not Latin, and not confusable in context. While there's a number of issues with colonizing orthographies, it's an easy assumption that if a colonized language doesn't have s or z in its alphabet, it doesn't have /s/ or /z/ in its language, since colonizers would have mapped /s/ to s in a heartbeat.

Comment: @AlexP Hawaiian is spelled phonemically because it had no writing system until American missionaries invented one.  I imagine this is generally true across Polynesia.  Also, there are regional dialects of Hawaiian which use /s/ or /t/ instead of /k/.

Comment: @prosfilaes My point is these arguments make plenty of sense to those of us with a familiarity with linguistics but for someone who doesn't, "This alphabet doesn't contain <S> so the language doesn't have /s/" is - at best - a partial argument, even if there's plenty of support based on the history of Hawaiian.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that even if the language lacks /s/ and /z/, native speakers can probably still make those sounds just fine with a little practice unless they have truly unusual physiology. They may not be good at clearly differentiating between the two (either when speaking themselves, or when listening), but both are still pretty easy for most people compared to stuff like /ɧ/, some of the click consonants or the implosives.

Comment: Perhaps the best-known example of Hawaiian's lack of sibilants is the loanword *kali**k**ima**k**a* for Christmas, with the S's replaced by K's.

Comment: @user253751: Yes, Hawaiian, Tahitian and Māori are quite closly related -- they are all Eastern Polynesian languages.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you have /ʃ/ and /ʒ/; given those, the absence of /s/ and /z/ is perfectly believable. [PHOIBLE](https://phoible.org/) lists over a thousand languages that have /ʃ/ and no /s/. Not always the most reliable source, given the vagaries of how they compare different inventories, but sometimes a good barometer.

Now, it's common for phonemes to "expand" to fit the available space. If there's no /s/ to contrast it with, it's easy for speakers to start pronouncing their /ʃ/ as [s] in some environments (or just arbitrarily). But you can get rid of this just as arbitrarily: perhaps using [s] is considered lower-class, or is associated with foreigners, or (given that the speakers are vampires) associated with living humans.

But if you don't feel like devoting pages to exploring vampire historical linguistics, this isn't really something that needs explaining. A language with /ʃ/ but not /s/ is far from unheard-of.

Answer (score 5):

**They *can* pronounce these consonants**

Both /s/ and /z/ *sibilant fricatives* are realized using the tongue, directing the air flow toward the teeth. Any mammal of the Homo genus can do the trick. Mammals have a tongue, genus Homo has a suitable mouth cavity to move the tongue forward, letting air escape near the teeth. Even when the front teeth are missing, or the tongue is short or partially cut off, genus Homo can produce /sj/ (shore) or /ch/ (choice)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibilant

**But they won't.. so what?**

So the explanation must be linguistic, or some cultural choice. I think it is up to you to choose: either, don't bother to explain, or put an explanation.

It will be clear to the reader vampires don't use these phonemes, when you would put a vampire poem in the story, or a vampire conversation.. There could be a *reason* for it, but I wonder if an explanation of vampire phonetics will add anything to a vampire story.

Answer (score 4):

Centuries ago, one of the great kings of your vampire people was born with a speech impediment.  He spoke with a severe lisp, and was never able to form the "s" or "z" sounds.  In order to make him not feel like an oddball, the royal court began imitating the lisp.  It soon became viewed as a sign of respect and had spread throughout the entire land.  By the end of that king's reign, the lisp had become embedded in the linguistic tradition and the "s" and "z" sounds were gone forever.

Comment: This absolutely sounds like something that could have happened in the real world as well, I have a vague recollection of hearing a similar factoid about Louis XIV or some other historical French king, but can't recall what it was about specifically so can't seem to find anything on google (and it was probably apocryphal anyways)

Comment: @roope it's a commonly given story for why standard Iberian Spanish pronounces z & c (before i & e) as a th sound rather than an s. As you say, it's apocryphal though

Answer (score 1):

Consider the airflow of the sybilant frictions as well discussed in @goodies' answer, for a physiological reason they wouldn't have such features in their language:

Vampires typically have very large canine teeth in order to pierce the skin of regular humans and exsanguinate them. Such teeth could result in making such airflow difficult to produce; from either an awkward mouth form, overbite, or obstruction by said canines.

Or you could say that people in the vampire culture inhale on /s/ and /z/, as is typical when feeding or sucking blood- and that it is a noise or act reserved for just that, rather than spoken communication.

Comment: Phenomenological reason? Do you mean "to do with phomemes"?

Comment: I think 'phenomenological' might be a bad word choice here, unless you particularly meant that this is a result of conscious perception of events. Perhaps you meant physiological?

Comment: Indeed, I did mean physiological; my brain fart.

Answer (score -3):

**Hiss. . . .**

Being the walking dead, vampires have lungs that don't work. This means they cannot blow up party balloons, and they cannot make sounds that require the release of air from the lungs.

Some of these sounds can be worked around. For example one can make an /f/ sound by moving your lower lip forward over your upper row of teeth. This triggers a *popping* release of air from the mouth that replaces the typical *hissing* release of air from the lungs.

Unfortunately esses and ezzes cannot be simulated this way.

Comment: No fantastical explanation is needed. There are real-world human languages spoken by real humans which do not have /s/ and /z/.

Comment: actually try this. Moving your lip against the upper teeth doesn't make anything like an f sound, or anything loud enough to be used in speech unless there's also accompanying airflow

Comment: @Tristan I can do it. The airflow comes from the mouth and not the lungs.

Comment: I was focussing on the description of you lip movement. Based on your description of it having a popping sound, I suspect you're describing an ejective (where airflow is generated by raisin the glottis). An ejective s is absolutely possible, although it is an unusual phoneme (PHOIBLE lists 16 languages with it, including Dakota and Amharic, and wikipedia lists Tlingit & some dialects of Hausa as having it too)

Comment: @ I don't know what those technical terms mean. What I do is similar to the "boots" from [the "boots and cats" beatboxing move](https://www.youtube.com/embed/aHIAvwf0eGw?start=59&end=66) only instead of putting my lips together I put my lower lip together with my top row of teeth.

Comment: @Daron ah yeah, the connection to beatboxing means that's pretty definitely ejective. More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ejective_consonant